# How do I add a command to current terminal history using python?

Tags: python, linux, bash, python-3.x, terminal

I have read other answers and the command is `history -s COMMAND`. 
I have also seen an example the following is used for accessing `history` through python.

```
shell_command = 'bash -i -c "history -r; history"'      
event = Popen(shell_command, shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, 
stderr=STDOUT)
output = event.communicate()
print(output)
```

But I am unable to use `history -s COMMAND` in the same way.

My main goal is to append a certain command to the user's current history so that the when the user presses the `up` button, the `"COMMAND"` shows up.

Comment: History is part of the internal state of a shell instance; you cannot affect that externally.

Comment: @chepner So this wouldn't be possible then?

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
import subprocess
command = "grep"
shell_command = 'bash -i -c "history -s; %s"' % command
event = subprocess.Popen(shell_command, shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
output = event.communicate()
print(output)
```

Comment: `grep` works. But it is not appearing in the terminal `history`.